# Cache error message

Tags: 6, status-messages

My Drupal 6 website has been working fine for many months. All of a sudden, it displays the following error messages:

> Warning: Can't find record in 'cache' query: SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache WHERE cid = 'variables' in /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 135
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/database.mysql.inc:135) in /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 729
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/database.mysql.inc:135) in /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 730
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/database.mysql.inc:135) in /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 731
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/database.mysql.inc:135) in /home/olo000/public_html/<>/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 732

How shuld I go about solving this?

Steps I have tried:
I've search extensively for other threads that discuss the same problem, but I've not found any.

Comment: Were there any changes (e.g. software update) on the server before this? Did you update some modules before this? Can you try restoring an older working backup and testing if you can replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by upgrading to Drupal 7 or 8

**[Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**